# Elements of Statistical Learning -2.4 Statistical Decision Theory：how to prove formula (2.12)

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics

I have a question, how to prove formula (2.12) in book 《Elements of Statistical Learning》

[image]

Comment: There might be an easier way, but I think if you take the expression $\int (Y- f(X))^{2} p(Y|X) dY$, which is a functional of $f(X)$, and take its functional derivative wrt $f(X)$ and set to zero, you will get that the $f(X)$ which makes this functional stationary is given by $E(Y|X)$

Comment: Actually, it's even simpler than that, because the aforementioned integral is over Y and not X, you can see it as a function of $f(X)$ rather than a functional. So you can just differentiate the expression wrt $f(X)$ and you should find that $f(x)=\int df Y\cdot P(Y|X)$ is the minimum.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I want to ask is the proof of formula 2.12, but after reading your answer, it seems to be about formula 2.13.@gazza89

Comment: I see. I'm not sure what you would need to convince you of 2.12? In order to minimise 2.11, if you manage to minimise everything inside the first expectation sign for fixed x, then you also minimise the integral over all x

Comment: This is a classic argument and looks very tricky the first time one encounters it. Would it help to write $c = f(X)$? The point is that by *defining* $f(X)$ to be any value of $c$ that minimizes the expression in $(2.12),$ you minimize every possible value of the argument of $E_X$ in $(2.11),$ which *obviously* minimizes $(2.11)$ -- there's no way to do any better!